# Oracle ADF: Need to show checkbox before label using selectBooleanCheckbox

Tags: checkbox, oracle-adf

I was trying to show checkbox before label using selectBooleanCheckbox in oracle ADF but it is showing checkbox after label.

```
<af:panelFormLayout id="pfl2" maxColumns="4" rows="1">  
  <af:iterator id="i2" value="#{pageFlowScope.StoreSearchMB.storeCreateCheckboxes}" var="List">
     <af:selectBooleanCheckbox label="#{List.VStore}" id="sbc2" inlineStyle="Color:#949595;font-size:18px;" value="#{List.VStStatus}"/>
  </af:iterator>
</af:panelFormLayout>
```

Could you please help me to get the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Text Attribute of af:selectBooleanCheckbox instead of label .
More here [Demo](http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/faces/components/selectBooleanCheckbox.jspx;jsessionid=6-XeESAFXxMFHYGhFYhid3lrAZ4g7Ds23oVf-DWU_k54Mb76N1G9!441076624)

Comment: the link doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 1):

Use the Text property of the checkbox instead of Label.